# Выделять ли запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

Подозреваю, что подобные вопросы уже были, и все-таки. Нужно ли ставить запятую после "вот" в предложении: "И вот(,) что пришло мне в голову..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, что запятая не нужна, так как "и вот" всего лишь соответственно усилительная и указательная частицы, подчеркивающие смысл дальнейшего.